Why does decodebin return this to me?
I'm running gstreamer using the gtkpaintable plugin to be able to manipulate a player. My code, which I call build_pipeline(), looks like this:
pub fn build_pipeline(&self) {
   
    let src = gst::ElementFactory::make("filesrc")
        .name("filesrc")
        .property("location", "sintel-trailer-480p_CdlXFG7r.webm")
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    
    let src2= gst::ElementFactory::make("videotestsrc").build().unwrap();

    let videoconvert = gst::ElementFactory::make("videoconvert")
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    let decodebin = gst::ElementFactory::make("decodebin").build().unwrap();

    self.pipeline
        .add_many(&[&src, &decodebin, &videoconvert, &self.gtksink])
        .unwrap();

    gst::Element::link(&src, &decodebin).unwrap();
    
    let videoconvert_weak = videoconvert.downgrade();
    let pipeline_weak = self.pipeline.downgrade();

    decodebin.connect_pad_added(move |_, src_pad| {
        println!("new pad {:?}", src_pad);
        
        let pipeline = match pipeline_weak.upgrade(){
            Some(pipeline) => pipeline,
            None => return,
        };

        let sink = match videoconvert_weak.upgrade() {
            None => return,
            Some(sink) => sink,
        };

        pipeline.remove(&sink).unwrap();
        pipeline.add(&sink).unwrap();
        
        sink.sync_state_with_parent().unwrap();

        let sink_pad = sink.static_pad("sink").unwrap();
        src_pad.link(&sink_pad).expect("Cannot link the decodebin source pad to the audioconvert sink pad");
    });    
      
    gst::Element::link(&videoconvert, &self.gtksink).unwrap(); 
}

Why does decodebin return this to me?
I'm running gstreamer using the gtkpaintable plugin to be able to manipulate a player. My code, which I call build_pipeline(), looks like this:
I know there is a problem related to decodebin because in my code it is not separating audio or video pads
but the video I'm trying to use has no audio and yet it returns:
    new pad Pad { inner: TypedObjectRef { inner: 0x725010015e50, type: GstDecodePad } }
0:00:00.118851133 114412 0x72502c001070 WARN           matroskademux matroska-demux.c:6115:gst_matroska_demux_loop:<matroskademux0> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:00.119882275 114412 0x72502c001070 WARN           matroskademux matroska-demux.c:6115:gst_matroska_demux_loop:<matroskademux0> error: streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)

How can it return internal data stream error if it recognized the stream type?
I tried to check if it was related to gtk4paintablesink and tested it on another project using gtksink and it presented the same problem.
